# How to add a horizontal line below section titles in the header area of a memoir class document

Tags: header-footer, memoir

As you can see the [memoir manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) contains a separator line between the header and the main text with the header displaying the section title. How to add that thing in my document. I have played around with many fancyhdr but nothing works. My tex file is

```
%%% DOCUMENTCLASS 
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[
a4paper, % Stock and paper size.
11pt, % Type size.
% article,
% oneside, 
onecolumn, % Only one column of text on a page.
% openright, % Each chapter will start on a recto page.
% openleft, % Each chapter will start on a verso page.
openany, % A chapter may start on either a recto or verso page.
]{memoir}

%%% PACKAGES 
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % If utf8 encoding
% \usepackage[lantin1]{inputenc} % If not utf8 encoding, then this is probably the way to go
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English please
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % Less badboxes

% \usepackage{kpfonts} %Font

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools} % Math

% \usepackage{tikz} % Figures
\usepackage{graphicx} % Include figures

%%% PAGE LAYOUT 
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.15\paperwidth}{*}{1} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{0.2\paperwidth}{*}{1}  % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout

%%% SECTIONAL DIVISIONS
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % Subsections (and higher) are numbered
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\makeatletter %
\makechapterstyle{standard}{
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{1\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{8\baselineskip}
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
  \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\normalfont\Large}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont \@chapapp}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\space}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Large}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{\vspace*{\midchapskip}\vspace*{5mm}}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\centering\bfseries\LARGE}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont ##1}
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{standard}

\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
\setparaindent{0pt}\setafterparaskip{0pt}

%%% FLOATS AND CAPTIONS
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter                  % You do not need to write [htpb] all the time
\renewcommand\fps@figure{htbp} %
\renewcommand\fps@table{htbp}  %
\makeatother                   %

\captiondelim{\space } % A space between caption name and text
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries} % Font of the caption name
\captiontitlefont{\small\normalfont} % Font of the caption text

\changecaptionwidth          % Change the width of the caption
\captionwidth{1\textwidth} %

%%% ABSTRACT
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\small\bfseries} % Font of abstract title
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0.1\textwidth} % Width of abstract
\setlength{\absrightindent}{\absleftindent}

%%% HEADER AND FOOTER 
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makepagestyle{standard} % Make standard pagestyle

\makeatletter                 % Define standard pagestyle
\makeevenfoot{standard}{}{}{} %
\makeoddfoot{standard}{}{}{}  %
\makeevenhead{standard}{\bfseries\thepage\normalfont\qquad\small\leftmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{standard}{}{}{\small\rightmark\qquad\bfseries\thepage}
% \makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother                  %

\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{standard}{
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{ \quad }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \quad }
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother                               %

\makepagestyle{chap} % Make new chapter pagestyle

\makeatletter
\makeevenfoot{chap}{}{\small\bfseries\thepage}{} % Define new chapter pagestyle
\makeoddfoot{chap}{}{\small\bfseries\thepage}{}  %
\makeevenhead{chap}{}{}{}   %
\makeoddhead{chap}{}{}{}    %
% \makeheadrule{chap}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{standard}               % Choosing pagestyle and chapter pagestyle
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{chap} %

%%% NEW COMMANDS
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\p}{\partial} %Partial
% Or what ever you want

%%% TABLE OF CONTENTS
%%%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\maxtocdepth{subsection} % Only parts, chapters and sections in the table of contents
\settocdepth{subsection}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}} % Add a \par to the end of the TOC

%%% INTERNAL HYPERLINKS
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}   % Internal hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
pdfborder={0 0 0},      % No borders around internal hyperlinks
pdfauthor={I am the Author} % author
}
\usepackage{memhfixc}   %

%%% THE DOCUMENT
%%% Where all the important stuff is included!
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\author{A. Author}
\title{The amazing Book about Timemachines}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just to put in some text

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents*
\clearpage

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-12]

\mainmatter

\chapter{How to Build a Timemachine}

\lipsum[1-13] 

\chapter{How to Destroy a Timemachine}

\lipsum[1-14]

\appendix

\chapter{Causality}

\lipsum[1-15]

\backmatter

%%% BIBLIOGRAPHY
%%% -------------------------------------------------------------

% \bibliographystyle{utphysics}
% \bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By uncommentating the line `\makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}` I get a rule in the header. Have you tried ?

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda thanks a ton, my bad. Rookie in memoir class. Please post the answer as a separate answer so that I can accept it. I would be delighted if you could also help me make the "Chapter X" text bigger in Chapter title pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a rule in the heading just uncomment the line
`\makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}`

To have a chapter name typset in a bigest size font replace `\Large` with `\LARGE`, `\huge` or `\Huge` in
`\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\normalfont\Large}`